# Multiple IN parameters in mySql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

MySQL wants parameters defined as follows

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`192.168.1.%` PROCEDURE `INSERTNEWREC`(
IN _LAST VARCHAR(10),
IN _FIRST VARCHAR(10),
IN _MI VARCHAR(10),
IN _DOB VARCHAR(10),
IN _GEN VARCHAR(10)

)
```

I have a multiple insert procedure with many parameters of the same type.

Is there a way to something like this:

```
IN _LAST, _FIRST, _MI, VARCHAR(10)
```

Comment: why would you want that?

Comment: Short answer, no there is not! Not in MySql and not in any other database in the market AFAIK.